# Evasive cause inside InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, reflection

Executing a Java code I capture an InvocationTargetException. Using the printStackTrace method I get the following:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:180)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at [...] (it doesn't really matters)
```

My code checks several programs written by other persons, so the cause shown by printStackTrace is varied. However, if I try to get just the internal cause using method getCause, the result is always a disgusting null!

Java 6 API says that, from release 1.4 in advance, getCause returns the cause exception provided during construction... should I assume that Method.invoke does not construct the exception properly, or am I losing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't the NullPointerException clear enough?

Comment: Are you sure you check a result of `getCause()`, not a result of `getCause().getMessage()` ? `NullPointerException` has `null` as a message.

Comment: Uhm... I was doing getCause().getMessage(), that's true... and the Exception is not null itself. Thanks. Nonetheless, the result is the same for an StackOverflowError, an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and some others. Is there a rule of thumb about which exceptions have message?

Comment: I can assure you that getCause() works as expected there.

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException has a message in Java 6. You shouldn't rely on the contents of the message, you should look at the type of the Exception.

Comment: Ok. thank you both @axtavt and @Peter Lawrey. I consider my question solved and stupid :-)

Comment: Can you answer the question yourself, then when you can accept that answer. Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.